# How do I write a Firebase security rule where unauthenticated users can write but only my trusted server can read?

Tags: firebase-security

I would like to write a rule where persons submitting a form from the webpage (unauthenticated) can `.write` and only the server can `.read` messages that are newer than two minutes old.

The server (App Engine Python-Flask instance) polls *Firebase* every two minutes., but I keep getting a JSON feedback  `{error: Permission Denied}`, instead of my requested data.

The Security Rules look like this:

```
{
"rules": {
    "leads": {
        ".write": true, 
        "$user_id": {
            ".write": true,
            ".read": "auth !== null && $user_id === auth.uid && data.child('CREATED').val() > (now - 120000)"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The simulator tells me:

```
Attempt to read /leads with auth={"provider":"custom","uid":"lead_checker"}
    /
    /leads

No .read rule allowed the operation.
Read was denied.
```

Can anyone spot what I am doing wrong or provide a suitable replacement?

Comment: You shouldn't have quotes around `'auth.uid'`.

Comment: Thanks, made the revision. Still gives the same error.

Comment: So you have a server that uses uid `lead_checker` and that server should have read access to all user nodes?

Comment: Yes. That is correct.

Comment: Allowing unauthenticated writes to other users' data is probably a security issue.

Comment: @Kato how can I structure it so that visitors (leads) to my site can submit a POST request to firebase without commiting to a user login,  and then have my server poll firebase for leads created less than two minutes ago, while still maintaining secure best practices?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you have a clause like `$user_id === auth.uid` in your read rule, it says: this data can be read when the current user's uid matches the node name. So for your user `lead_checker` is means that it can read the node named `lead_checker`.

What you're probably looking to do is to allow `lead_checker` read access to each user node:

```
{
  "rules": {
    "leads": {
        "$user_id": {
            ".write": true,
            ".read": "auth.uid == 'lead_checker'"
        }
    }
  }
}
```

With this the lead checker can reach each node under `leads`. Note that it still can't read the `leads` node itself. If that is needed, move the read rule one level up:

```
{
  "rules": {
    "leads": {
        ".read": "auth.uid == 'lead_checker'"
        "$user_id": {
            ".write": true,
        }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Ok, the auth.uid works the way I want it. Thanks! Do I need to do a live test on the 'CREATED' child, I am now given this when I include the .val() condition:

`Attempt to read /leads with auth={"provider":"custom","uid":"lead_checker"}
 /
 /leads: "auth.uid === 'lead_checker' && data.child('CREATED').val() > (now - 120000)"
5:50: Type error: > only operates on numbers and strings.
  => false

No .read rule allowed the operation.
Read was denied.`

Comment: `leads` doesn't have a child `CREATED`, so that will always fail indeed. If you want to also check the `CREATED`, you will have to push the rule down. But that means you won't be able to get the list of leads (since you'll remove read access from `leads` itself).

Comment: So instead of using && I need to get to the `'CREATED'` as a grand child of the `leads`. If The web facing client did not create a `auth.uid` how do i get to `'CREATED'`?